# Crippling load times and framerate drop in the PS3 version

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I have Skyrim for the PS3 and the PC. On the PC load time is no more than 3 seconds for anywhere Skyrim on ultra settings, no lag whatsoever and a much higher detail than on the PS3.

However, my PS3 version has the crippling framerate drop and much longer load times after about 20+ hours and a 8 mb save file (more than double that on PC and no problems), I no idea what the issue is. Could be a cache problem?

Comment: This is a known issue and the bug fix is supposed to come the week after thanksgiving. I can't remember what the workaround is supposed to be, but I remember hearing about one.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known issue for the PS3](http://www.officialplaystationmagazine.co.uk/2011/11/17/skyrim-are-you-suffering-save-file-related-lag/).  Bethesda is working on a patch, and it's slated to be released after Thanksgiving.

**Update**: Looks like [there'll be a patch in a few weeks for this issue](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/326691/skyrim-update-within-two-weeks-says-bethesda/?attr=CVG-General-RSS&cid=OTC-RSS).